# Reset manipulated elements of SVG object

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg

In html I have an svg of the same origin in an object tag. In javascript, I have loaded this object's content document, searched for the elements I wanted to manipulate, and manipulated them. In this case, I made their opacity 0. Now I can't seem to get the elements to change back on a different operation.

The body onloads with this method, which clears some things away... please forgive the context here

```
function clearDoge(){
    var doge = document.getElementById('doge').contentDocument;
    var artifactPaths = doge.querySelectorAll('g.artifact > path');
    for(var i=0; i<artifactPaths.length; i++) {
        artifactPaths[i].style.opacity = "0";
    }
}
```

Then, when the user has performed an action, I want to reset the whole image and clear only a select few elements. To reset:

```
function resetDoge(){
    document.getElementById("doge-container").innerHTML = "<object id='doge' data='doge.svg' type='image/svg+xml' width='100%' height='100%' style='display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;'> </object>";
}
```

Then I want to only hide certain elements

```
function rainyDoge(){
    var doge = document.getElementById('doge').contentDocument;
    var rainyPaths = doge.querySelectorAll('g.rainy > path');
    for(var i=0; i<rainyPaths.length; i++) {
        rainyPaths[i].style.opacity = "0";
    }
}
```

However, the result is that the svg is reset, but the new desired action does not affect the image.

Comment: Where are the elements with class `.rainy`? Do they still have that class after the reset?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong that I can see.  Can you make a jsfiddle or similar so we can see the code in action?

Comment: Yes, the source is available on my github. https://github.com/TurtleDynasty/Doge-Weather

Comment: Are you calling rainyDoge only after the onload event of resetDoge?

Comment: Ah... Yes I am... I can see now how that could be a problem... Hmm...

Comment: FIXED!! @RobertLongson Showing the problem to a friend in a coffee shop, he pointed out that writing all the elements, then removing the ones I don't want is a bad solution - why not just write the ones I _do_ want? So that eliminates about two steps, and solved the problem right away! When I have worked out the other bugs, I will update the repo. Thanks all!